# Content disappears when changing template using templavoila

Tags: typo3, templavoila

I haven't worked with templaVoila for a while but I'm now tasked with creating a few new templates for a client using templaVoila as template engine.

I have created the new templates, but whenever I go to a page with content and change template, the content "disappears" into Non-used elements

I made sure both old and new template use the same colPos for content.

Is there any way to avoid this behaviour?

The site is using TYPO3 4.5 and templaVoila 1.8.0

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the green page icon and simply assign the unused elements to a TV column.  You only need to do it once, but I haven't found a way around doing it.